# What does "Object.call" mean?

Tags: javascript, oop

```
function bb_graphics_GraphicsContext(){
    Object.call(this);
    this.bbdevice=null;
    this.bbmatrixSp=0;
    this.bbix=1.000000;
    this.bbiy=0;
    this.bbjx=0;
    this.bbjy=1.000000;
    this.bbtx=0;
    this.bbty=0;
    this.bbtformed=0;
    this.bbmatDirty=0;
    this.bbcolor_r=0;
    this.bbcolor_g=0;
    this.bbcolor_b=0;
    this.bbalpha=0;
    this.bbblend=0;
    this.bbscissor_x=0;
    this.bbscissor_y=0;
    this.bbscissor_width=0;
    this.bbscissor_height=0;
    this.bbmatrixStack=new_number_array(192);
}
```

What does `Object.call(this)` mean?

Comment: You might want to make it clear that you're wondering why in particular a constructor (this "bb_graphics_GraphicsContext" function) would do that with its own `this` reference.

Comment: It was considered to be constructor. But if it's, have to call outside of the function.

Comment: Added extra commentary at the end of my answer to get at what it does, and offer musings as to why it was done.

Comment: Maybe some more context would help. When and how is `bb_graphics_GraphicsContext` called? Right now the best answer you have is mostly conjecture.

Answer (score 13):

Functions in JavaScript are full-fledged objects. They also, when passed as an argument to another function, don't retain their scope. So, in the following code...

```
var obj1 = {
    property1: "blah",
    method1: function () {
        alert(this.property1);
        // do stuff
    }
 };

 function func1 (passedFunction) {
     passedFunction();
     // do other stuff
 }

 func1(obj1.method1);
```

... `func1` will call `obj1.method1`, but it won't `alert` the value of `obj1`'s `property1`, because all we've done is pass the function object, not its `this` context. That's where `call` and `apply` come in. They allow you to inject scope, tell the function what the meaning of `this` will be. The following example works:

```
var obj1 = {
    property1: "blah",
    method1: function () {
        alert(this.property1);
        // do stuff
    }
 };

 function func1 (passedObject, passedFunction) {
     passedFunction.call(passedObject);
     // do other stuff
 }

 func1(ob1, obj1.method1);
```

Now, we've forced or explicitly told `obj1.method1` what its context will by invoking `call`, and passing it the object it's to use as `this`.

`call` and `apply` are almost identical, except for how they handle additional arguments to the function being invoked. See these articles on MDN for more information: [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/).

All of this having been said, `bb_graphics_GraphicsContext` is a constructor. (Which you've probably guessed.) You invoke it by using the `new` keyword, `var obj1 = new bb_graphics_GraphicsContext();`. When it reaches line 1 of the function, it takes the `this` object, and calls the generic `Object` constructor, explicitly injecting the new object `this` (in the `bb_graphics_GraphicsContext` constructor) as the `this` of the `Object` constructor. I'd assume the writer of this function/constructor was doing this to make sure that the newly created object in `bb_graphics_GraphicsContext` was getting all the base methods of the base `Object`. But I don't know why this would be necessary, as if you call `bb_graphics_GraphicsContext` with the `new` keyword it will grab all these properties naturally.

Comment: All that is completely true, but it's *still* not answering the question of *why* someone would do that with the `Object` constructor.

Comment: is it possible that someone wanted to redefine Object  later??

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that that's possible in JavaScript. Wait... just tried it in Safari (on a Mac). Yep, sure is possible, but I doubt anyone would ever want to.

Answer (score 0):

Object.call will execute a certain function under the provided context,  it can be used to call functions from one object on an other.

The mozilla dev network provides a very good explanation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: The "certain function" in this case being the `Object` constructor function itself.

Answer (score 0):

This will do absolutely nothing except wasting resource and memory allocation.

If the Object.call(this) will have been assigned to a variable or property of the function constructor bb_graphics_GraphicsContext

this.myObject = Object.call(this)

The only thing that you get in that instance is an empty object "THAT DO NO HOLD THE PROVIDED CONTEXT"

```
function MyConstructor(){
    this.test01 = 0;
    var b = Object.call(this); // similar to b = {}; or b = new Object()
    console.log(b); // log object 
    console.log(b.test); // log undefined
    this.test = 1;
}

var myObject = new MyConstructor();

console.log(myObject, window.test01)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Object.call will probably do nothing as expressed here, the concept might be important. Basically, the example you will see on inheritance in the Node.js [documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor) is:

```
const util = require('util');
const EventEmitter = require('events');

function MyStream() {
  EventEmitter.call(this);
}

util.inherits(MyStream, EventEmitter);
```

The `util.inherits` will make a new `MyStream` inherit (have the same prototype as) `EventEmmiter`. This could be enough if we are interested in MyStream having access to the functions inherited through the `EventEmmiter` prototype. But what if there are variables passed on construction? What if we have:

```
function MyObject() {
    this.code = "2nV_ahR";
}
```

In this case, the `code` variable is passed on runtime when `MyObject` gets instantiated. Therefore, a subclass needs to pass:

```
function MySubObject() {
    MyObject.call(this);
}
```

In order to inherit the `code` variable. What [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) does accept a parameter that sets the `this` variable. So... when I do `var o = new MySubObject()`, the `this` inside of `MySubObject` refers to `o`, which is then passed to the `call` method, so that when `MyObject` does `this.code = ...` it is actually passing the `code` to `o`!

Answer (score -2):

Every JavaScript function has a `toString()`, `call()` and `apply()`.

Read more about them on [this odetocode.com article](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx)

Comment: i know that. I'd like to know what happens in this context. What does this keyword refer to?? What happens after that call - Object.call(this);

Comment: It turns to a recursive function.

Comment: @miqbal uhh ... what?  It doesn't turn anything into a recursive function; what would that even mean?

Comment: @Pointy what's the difference, function a() { a(); var b=0;}

Comment: That's not what's going on in the OP, not at all. Your example there is in fact an infinitely recursive bug; the code in the OP is just invoking the `Object` constructor.  It's just an ordinary function call to a **different** function.

Comment: Exactly recursive bug. But constructor in JS doesn't work like you said. He has to use "new" outside of the function.